# Microsoft Publisher 2013 change Language (or other properties) for multiple elements at once

Tags: language, spell-check, microsoft-publisher

Is there a way to change language for **all** text boxes in a Publisher 2013 document at once?

I have an existing file with a bunch of text boxes set to a wrong language, which is screwing up spell checking and hyphenation. I also don't know [how to disable hyphenation](https://superuser.com/q/649010/25438), but I don't even know how to do it for a single text box.

So, what I **do know** is how to change language for a single text box, i.e.:

1. Click on a single text box,
2. Select all text using `Ctrl+A`,
3. Review -> Language -> Set proofing language.

But since it's a large document, it's rather cumbersome, and a bit strange that it's not possible to at least select all boxes on a single page and change their properties. For example, if I select two or more text boxes, I am also unable to change their Font type or size, which is also something that is pretty easy to do in, say, Visio or Word.

Is there a way to do change properties of multiple Publisher elements at once?

Comment: This is only possible if you purchased the language packs for Publisher.

Comment: @Ramhound: I am asking how to change language for **all** text boxes. Doing it manually works correctly as I've described above, but involves going through all text boxes, one by one, which I'd like to avoid. So, I think it's obvious I have Publisher installed (just in case you were wondering) and I have appropriate language packs installed (to answer your rather irrelevant comment). Also, all Office apps all share the same language packs (at least in Office 2013), so there is no such thing as "language packs for Publisher".

Comment: You can install Publisher without any other Office product installed.   Asking if you have multiple language packs isn't irrelevant.

Comment: @Ramhound: it's irrelevant, because I didn't ask if it's possible to change language of an element in Publisher, I specifically asked if it's possible to change that property for all elements at once. So, while it obviously is *impossible* if I don't have them installed, I am interested in **how** exactly it is possible. "This will only work if you purchased Publisher" would be equally meaningful for my question.

Comment: If you say so.  What exactly is wrong with the method you are using?  Your question is not clear if the method your currently using even works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a crude macro to do this:

```
Sub AllTextboxesLanguageToSpanish()

    Dim s As Shape
    Dim p As Page

    For Each p In ThisDocument.Pages

        For Each s In p.Shapes

        On Error Resume Next

            If s.TextFrame.HasText Then
                s.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = 21514
            End If

        Next s

    Next p

End Sub
```

If you replace "21514" (Spanish (United States)) with the code for another language, you should be fine. Just run it from the VBA editor (Alt+F11).

Comment: You can use constants such as `msoLanguageIDEnglishUS`

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still relevant.  As far as I have been able to work out this is not possible.  As far as I can tell there are three independent language settings for Microsoft Publisher:

-The "Editing Language" (Options - Language - Choose Editing Languages)

-The language for each text box (Select the text box - Review - Language - Set Proofing Language)

-Some internal setting that determines the default proofing language for a text box.  In my tests this is **not** impacted by changing the Editing Language.  I have found no way to change it thus far.

Ultimately I have only been able to change language settings individually for each text-box.  The "Editing Language" in the main options menu seems to have no impact on any files (old or new).  As far as I can tell the only bit it does is confirm that the user has paid for the language packs.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the hyphenation in the single box, go to text box on the ribbon, and there should be an item for hyphenation. Uncheck the 'automatic hyphenation' box. To avoid hyphenation in any new document, go to Options, and there should be an option there somewhere.